# Brown spots with black edges on tomato leaves

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, fungus

I've got some brown spots with black edges on my tomatoes leaves - looking at other questions on this site with similar problems, none of them look quite right to me. I've attached pictures below.

This is affecting every single tomato plant (~35), and is on nearly every single leaf, new and old. Fruit and stems don't seem affected. To my eye, what stands out about this problem is that it's only affecting the leaves between the veins - it is basically not crossing the vein at all.

These plants have been in the ground for a few weeks after 4-6 weeks in a greenhouse, so they are not really juvenile - some have set fruit. I hardened them off for around a week before planting them. No other plants are affected (peppers, basil, cukes, etc).

(I know in the super-zoom pictures you also can see lots of little white spots - I'm pretty sure that's pollen, it brushes right off for the most part.)

Any ideas?

[image]
[image]